# Display image from form on online view

Tags: php, database, forms

I'm no pro on all this, so I apologize if it's a simple thing.

I have a form that submits the data to the database, sends an email and stores it online for users to view.

The first 2 are working perfectly and the 3rd options (viewing online) is almost perfect.

As part of the survey users have a star rating system that they rate from 1 - 5. This then emails as an image of their star rating as well as the number. I would like the same image to appear on the online view version. At the moment, it does appear but it's not showing their rating (it's just the plain image named `star.jpg`).

The following is my code (please let me know if you need to see more):

```
<?php
class guestquestionnaireEntry {
    public $id, $date_submitted, $choice, $expectations, $res, $res_information,
        $entry;

public function __construct()
    {
        $img            =   "<img src='http://www.myURL.com/guestquestionnaire/images/star".$_POST['res'].".jpg'>";
        $img2           =   "<img src='http://www.myURL.com/guestquestionnaire/images/star".$_POST['res_information'].".jpg'>";
        $this->entry    =   "
        <table border='1' width='800px' align='center'>
            <tr>
                <td><b>{$this->date_submitted} </b></td>
            </tr>
            <BR>
            <tr>
                <td>What made you choose us for your recent stay? </td>
                <td>{$this->choice}</td>
            </tr>
            <BR>
            <tr>
                <td> Did our hotel meet your expectations as advertised? If no, please state why. </td>
                <td>{$this->expectations} </td>
            </tr>
            <BR>
            <tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #000;'>
                <td colspan='3'>Making your Reservation</td>
            </tr>
            <BR>
            <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                <td>Ease of making your reservation: </td>
                <td width='40%'>$img</td>
                <td width='5%'>{$this->res}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                <td>Hotel information offered: </td>
                <td width='40%'>$img2</td>
                <td width='5%'>{$this->res_information}</td>
            </tr>...
```

**Here is how I use it:**

```
try {
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***', '***', '***');
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }

 $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire');
 $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'guestquestionnaireEntry');
 while($r = $query->fetch()) {
      echo $r->entry, '<br>';
}

?>
```

My images are then named `star.jpg`, `star1.jpg`, `star2.jpg`, etc.

Frontend form coding (again, please let me know if you need more):

```
<div id="third_step">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="question">
            <h1>Making Your Reservation</h1>
            <p>When making your reservation, how would you rate the following?</p>
        </div>
        <BR />
        <div class="question-sub">
            <p>Ease of making your reservation</p>
        </div>
        <span class="rating">
            <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-1" name="res" value="5">
            <label for="rating-input-1-1" class="rating-star"></label>
            <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-2" name="res" value="4">
            <label for="rating-input-1-2" class="rating-star"></label>        
            <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-3" name="res" value="3">
            <label for="rating-input-1-3" class="rating-star"></label>        
            <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-4" name="res" value="2">
            <label for="rating-input-1-4" class="rating-star"></label>       
            <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-1-5" name="res" value="1">
            <label for="rating-input-1-5" class="rating-star"></label>
        </span>
        <br>
        <div class="question-sub">
            <BR />
            <p>Hotel information offered</p>
        </div>
        <span class="rating">
            <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-2-5" name="res_information" value="5">
            <label for="rating-input-2-5" class="rating-star"></label>
            <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-2-4" name="res_information" value="4">
            <label for="rating-input-2-4" class="rating-star"></label>
            <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-2-3" name="res_information" value="3">
            <label for="rating-input-2-3" class="rating-star"></label>
            <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-2-2" name="res_information" value="2">
            <label for="rating-input-2-2" class="rating-star"></label>
            <input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-input-2-1" name="res_information" value="1">
            <label for="rating-input-2-1" class="rating-star"></label>
        </span>
```

I suspect the problem and (hopefully) the easy fix is within the first 2 lines `$img="<img src....` since this is the part that doesn't seem to be calling properly. I suspect the coding needs to be different for displaying the information?

Comment: Do you store a digit, like a number from 1 to 5, depending on what they have chosen, correct?

Comment: Also, how do you populate all the `$this` variables since this is the `construct()`?

Comment: Correct. And not sure? It's working though...

Comment: How do you use this class? Can you post an example of that?

Comment: I've updated my code above. Please let me know if you need to see more code. I (think) this might answer your question though, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out your code. When they click submit, it reloads the page, saves the registration, then sends them an email confirmation? Is that correct? It's hard to tell from your snippits

Comment: If not, then you can't use `$_POST`. You would have to grab the digit from your database.

Comment: I believe '$_POST' is what needs changing, i'm just not sure what to. When they click 'submit' they get diverted to a thank you page, their response gets emailed and it also gets stored in a database.

Comment: It does need changing. Is your code above on the thank you page, or the submit page, or neither.

Comment: It's on the page that allows people to view the results.

Comment: i.e. it pulls the information FROM the database

Comment: Then you have to populate it from the database

Comment: Right, but how do I do that?

Comment: Likely the same way you use the other variables `$this->column_name`

Comment: Eugh, I had tried that and it didn't work. Just tried again but removed an extra period and it worked. Sorry, though it was something more complex - turns out I just needed to keep going with that idea. Thanks for all your help!